# Python strings and integer

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a .csv file with data like this:

```
uc007ayl.1,ENSMUSG00000041439

uc009mkn.1,ENSMUSG00000031708

uc009mkn.1,ENSMUSG00000035491
```

I have some codes that read them column by column

```
    import csv
    import os.path
    #open files + readlines
    with open("C:/Users/Ivan Wong/Desktop/Placement/Lists of targets/Mouse/UCSC to Ensembl.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter = ',')
        #find files with the name in 1st row
        for row in reader:
            graph_filename = os.path.join("C:/Users/Ivan Wong/Desktop/Placement/Interesting reading/3'ORF",row[0]+"_nt_counts.txt.png")
            if os.path.exists(graph_filename):
                y = row[0]+'_nt_counts.txt'  
                r = open('C:/Users/Ivan Wong/Desktop/Placement/fp_mesc_nochx/'+y, 'r')
                k = r.readlines()
                r.close
                del k[:1]
                k = map(lambda s: s.strip(), k)
                interger = map(int, k)   
                import iter

tools
            #adding the numbers for every 3 rows
            def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
                "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
                args = [iter(iterable)] * n
                return itertools.izip_longest(*args, fillvalue=fillvalue)
            result = map(sum, grouper(3, interger, 0))
            e = row[1]
```

Now I can say

```
print row[1]
```

to make it show the 2nd column only. I needed to do this because I will be finding these names in another file. But I have a problem because I think python is reading those names in this way:

"E", "N", "S", "M", "U", "S" etc.

This causes a problem now because I won't able to find the match names from another folder. Anyone know where is the problem and how to fix it?

Comment: Why are you telling `csv.reader` that the delimiter is `','` when there don't seem to be any commas in your text file?

Comment: Is your file delimited by `' '` or by `','`?

Comment: @DSM One small mistake, I said its a .txt file but I actually converted it to .csv and they do have a ',' between the 1st and 2nd column

Comment: @ivanhoifung: I can't reproduce this.  You say `print row[1]` but your code doesn't mention a `row`.  Could you edit your question to include the code you're actually using?  [Incidentally, does your filename really have two asterisks in it?]

Comment: @DSM A bit too complicated for me to understand, I just put the whole codes on see if this work now

Comment: Can you add a comment to your code where the problem is occurring, specifically which variable or statement is behaving incorrectly and how you would like it to behave?

Comment: @Jesse Harris Sorry I am still new to Python and not very used to this sort of things. The problem I found is not included in the code above (I deleted it). But it was something like this :
listlength = len(e)
print listlength
and this shows 18, 18, 18, 18, 18
so I think it is reading this name "ENSMUSG00000041439" letter by letter hence the result 18, and this have a problem when I am trying to use them to find the names in another file

Comment: @ivanhoifung: but *shouldn't* it show 18? "ENSMUSG00000041439" is a string with 18 characters.  Try typing `print len("apple")` at the console, it'll say `5`.

Comment: @DSM maybe its just with my bad python knowledge, I was hoping it shows the length of this list, hence I have above 50 names and it giving me 50

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`row[1]` is not the whole second column of the file. It is just the second field in the current row i.e., just one of many values in the second column.

`row[1]` is a string in your case. Strings in Python are also sequences; you can call `len(some_string)` to find out length of string, take an element at a given position `pos`: `some_string[pos]`, etc.